# xlrd error unsupported format

Tags: python, xlrd

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import xlrd

dls = 'http://market.finance.sina.com.cn/downxls.php?date=2018-03- 
06&symbol=sh601169'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(dls, "test.xls")

book = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Source")
```

Hi everyone, I want to download and extract data from a link but I always got this error:

> XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xb3\xc9\xbd\xbb\xca\xb1\xbc\xe4'

I've checked the folder and test.xls is downloaded in the current folder and it is .xls format. 
Any idea what went wrong? what does `b'\xb3..` imply? 
Thanks!